# Find out n*(n+1)/2 % m

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I need to find the value of

$$ n(n+1)/2 \pmod m $$

Note: $n \leq 10^{18}$ So intermediate calculations may overflow (I'm using a 64 bit data type to store **n**)

If m is odd, I can simply find x in $ 2^{-1} \equiv x \pmod m $ and multiply that to $ (n \mod m) * ((n+1) \mod m) $

But what if m is even? The multiplicative inverse won't exist. How do I calculate it then?

n*(n+1) is always an even integer, and if m is even, $ n(n+1) \mod m $ will also be even. So will just dividing by 2 give me the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should condition on the parity of $n$, not $m$.

If $n = 2k$ is even, then $n(n+1)/2 = k(2k+1)$. Compute $k \mod m$. Call the result $r$. Then the answer is $r(2r+1) \mod m$.

If $n = 2k-1$ is odd, then $n(n+1)/2 = k(2k-1)$. Compute $k \mod m$. Call the result $r$. Then the answer is $r(2r-1) \mod m$.

Comment: I was considering parity of m because I need to find out inverse(2) mod m. If m is odd, the inverse will always exist, so there's no problem

Comment: With the solution I just gave you, you don't have to compute that inverse.

Comment: @Rushil Modular fractions are not well-defined if the denominator is not coprime to the modules, e.g. [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque Yes I know, that's why I was wondering what to do if the inverse won't exist.

Comment: @Rushil Does your expression mean take the *integer* $\, k := n(n+2)/2\,$ then reduce it mod $m,\,$ or does it instead denote the solution(s) of $\, 2x\equiv n(n+1)\pmod m?\,$ The latter will have $2$ solutions when $\,m\,$ is even, e.g. $\,2x\equiv 6\pmod{10}\iff x\equiv 3\pmod 5\iff x\equiv 3,8\pmod{10}\  $ when $\ m=10,\ n = 2\ $ so the "fraction" $\,x = 6/2\,$ is not well-defined mod $\,10.\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque My expression is the former one.

Comment: @Rushil Then the description in the question is incorrect since the quotient operation denotes an operation on *integers* (not modular integers).

Comment: n(n+1)/2 is an integer. I want to take that integer mod m. I don't quite understand what is wrong with that

Comment: @Rushil The point is that your question talks about computing modular inverses of $2$ etc, bit these never occur if the quotient denotes a quotient of integers. What you wrote in the question makes it seem like the denotation is actually the latter one I mentioned above, where the quitient (or fraction) is a modular one.

Comment: @Rushil - while $n(n+1)/2$ is indeed an integer, it is not a good idea to compute $n(n+1)/2 \% m$ as $(n \% m) \cdot ((n+1) \% m) \cdot (2^{-1} \% m)$ as you have attempted to do. It can lead to errors or to confusion (as in this case).

Comment: @HansEngler Yes I realize that now