# Can someone clarify the notation of x $\equiv$ -8 $\equiv$ 6 ($\bmod$ 7)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, computer-science, congruences

This is an example from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications 
[image]

This is example 1 that this example references 
[image]

And here's Theorem 1 that the example references
[image]

Example 1 makes sense. We have to determine if the inverse of 3 modulo 7 exists first of all. It will exist based on theorem 1 if m > 1, which it is in this case bc m = 7 and if gcd(3, 7) is 1 - definition of relatively prime.

To determine if gcd(3, 7) is 1, you can use Euclid's Algorithm,

7 = 3(2) + 1

3 = 1(3) + 0

In this case, 1 is the gcd because it is last remainder before the remainder goes to zero. $\equiv$

Now you know the inverse exists. To find the actual inverse, you want the inverse to be in the form

a'a $\equiv$  1 $\bmod$ m

where a' would be the inverse.

To do this, you would need to use Bezout's Theorem that gcd(a, b) = sa + tb, so from my work in Euclid's Theorem, you can see

7 = 3(2) + 1

-2(3) + 1(7) = 1

then

-2(3) - 1 = -1(7)

-2(3) $\equiv$ 1$\bmod$(7) which is in the form of a'a $\equiv$  1 $\bmod$ m, so a' or the inverse of a modulo m is -2.

Here's where I get lost. In example 3, the author uses the result he got from the inverse to solve the linear congruence of 3x $\equiv$ 4(mod 7).

I understand that -6 $\equiv$ 1 ($\bmod$ 7) and -8 $\equiv$ 6 ($\bmod$ 7), but how does that lead to x $\equiv$  -8 $\equiv$ 6 ($\bmod$ 7)? What does that even mean?

Comment: difference is a multiple of 7

Comment: Since $-2$ is the inverse of $3$ modulo 7 (which you can verify since $(-2)(3)=-6 \equiv 1$ (mod 7)), multiply both sides of the congruence $3x \equiv 4$ (mod 7) by $-2$ to obtain... what?

Comment: And the congruence $x\equiv 6$ (mod 7) means that $x-6$ is divisible by $7$, by definition. I think of it as meaning that $x$ is $6$ higher than some multiple of $7$ (hence it might be 13, 27, 34, etc).

Comment: @WillJagy I get that  -6 ≡ 1 (mod 7) means difference is a multiple of 7. But what does x ≡ -8 ≡ 6 (mod 7)? mean?

Comment: It means $-8-6 = -14 = (-2) \cdot 7$ is a multiple of 7. Or $6 - (-8) = 14$

Comment: @WillJagy  wheres the x though?

Comment: If you are referring to $3x \equiv 4 \pmod 7,$ the quick way is to multiply by $5$ to get $15 x \equiv 20 \pmod 7,$ or $x \equiv 6 \pmod 7.$

Comment: @WillJagy No I mean like for  x ≡ -8 ≡ 6 (mod 7), you said      " 
It means −8−6=−14=(−2)⋅7 is a multiple of 7. Or 6−(−8)=14" but you never mention x

Comment: @WillJagy I think i get it now. It's saying  x ≡ -8(mod 7) and x  = 6(mod 7) are the same thing?

Comment: @committedandroider, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\qquad\ \  3\,x\,\equiv\, 4 \pmod 7\ $ scaled by $\ {-2}\equiv 3^{-1}_{\phantom{I_{I_{I_I}}}} $ yields

$\smash[t]{\ \ \overbrace{-2\cdot 3}^{\Large\ \equiv\, \color{#c00}1}\,x\,\equiv\,\overbrace{-2\cdot 4}^{\Large\! \equiv\, \color{#0a0}6}\pmod 7}$

$\ \Rightarrow\ \color{#c00}1\cdot x\equiv \color{#0a0}6\pmod 7,\, $ where we've used the [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) to scale it.

Indeed $\ x\equiv 6\,\Rightarrow\, 3x \equiv 18\equiv 4\pmod 7$

Alternatively $\ x\,\equiv\ \dfrac{4}{3}\,\equiv\, \dfrac{-3}3\,\equiv\, {-}1\,\equiv\, 6 $

**Beware** $ $ Modular fraction arithmetic is well-defined only for fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion.

Comment: For Congruence product rule A≡a,  and  B≡b ⇒ AB≡ab   (mod m), how is  −2⋅3 $\equiv$ 1?

Comment: @com Use $\ {-}2\equiv -2\,$ times $\,3x\equiv 4,\,$ which scales the latter by $\,-2\,$ as in the answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I thought the whole point of this $\equiv$ sign was to go along with a  modulus expression like 9 $\equiv$ 4(mod 5) is saying the difference between 9 and 4 is a multiple 5. What does it mean when you don't have the modular expression?

Comment: @com  Some writers omit the $\!\pmod m\,$ if the modulus is clear from the context. That is not advised if one is working with congruences wrt more than one modulus (possible ambiguity).

Comment: I don't get how -2 * 3 is scaled to 1 and -2 * 4 is scaled to 6?

Comment: @com No scaling there, just modular arithmetic $\,-2(3)\equiv -6\equiv 7-6\equiv 1,\,$ and $\,-2(4)\equiv -8\equiv 2(7)-8\equiv 6.\ $ Recall $\, a\equiv a+7n\pmod 7,\ $ since $\,7\,$ divides their difference. $\ $

Comment: Why do you do 2 * 7 from −2(4)≡−8≡2(7)−8 but just 7 in −2(3)≡−6≡7−6?

Comment: @com I keep adding $\,7\,$ till I get a rep $\,n\,$ in the standard range $\,0\le n < 7 = m.\ \ $

Comment: Oh because you want remainder to be non zero right. So essentially -6 mod 7 is -1 remainder 1 and -8 mod 7 is -2 remainder 6?

Comment: @com The integers $\, -8+7n\,$ are all $\equiv -8\pmod 7.\,$ From that set we usually choose the least nonnegative element as the canonical representative, here $\, -8+7(2) = 6.\ \ $

Comment: How did you go from x≡6 to 3x≡18? Based on what you talked about previously, wouldn't you want to use modular arithmetic to break the 18 in 3x ≡ 18(mod 7) into 4? because 18 = 7(2) + 4?

Comment: @com As above, we use the Congruence Product Rule to scale $\,x\equiv 6\,$ by $\,3.\,$ Yes, we reduce $\,18\,$ to its least positive rep $\,4\,$ by subtracting $\,7\,$ twice, which is equivalent to computing the remainder left when dividing $\,18\,$ by $\,7,\,$ i.e. $\,4 = 18\ {\rm mod}\ 7.\ \ $

Comment: oh the two ≡ signs in 3x≡18≡4(mod7) has tripped me up for a while now. So you can just simply this down to 3x ≡4(mod7)?

Comment: @com Right, just like an ordinary equality, $\,a\equiv b\equiv c\,$ means $\,a\equiv b,\ b\equiv c,\ $ so $\ a\equiv c\,$ follows by *transitivity* (congruence is an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation)). Again, you want to think of congruence equations just like ordinary equations, and learn to manipulate these generalized equations just as skillfully, by exploiting their many common properties.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find solutions to the equivalence $3x \equiv 4 \pmod{7}$.  What the author is saying is that both $-8$ and $6$ are solutions to the equivalence, which we can verify by direct substitution.

If we substitute $-8$ for $x$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
3(-8) & \equiv -24 \pmod{7}\\
      & \equiv -28 + 4 \pmod{7}\\
      & \equiv -4 \cdot 7 + 4 \pmod{7}\\
      & \equiv 4 \pmod{7}
\end{align*}
If we substitute $6$ for $x$, we obtain
\begin{align*}
3 \cdot 6 & \equiv 18 \pmod{7}\\
          & \equiv 14 + 4 \pmod{7}\\
          & \equiv 2 \cdot 7 + 4 \pmod{7}\\
          & \equiv 4 \pmod{7}
\end{align*}
Moreover, 
\begin{align*}
-8 & \equiv -14 + 6 \pmod{7}\\
   & \equiv -2 \cdot 7 + 6 \pmod{7}\\
   & \equiv 6 \pmod{7}
\end{align*} 
In fact, if $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $6 + 7n$ is a solution to the equivalence since 
\begin{align*}
3(6 + 7n) & \equiv 18 + 21n \pmod{7}\\
          & \equiv 14 + 4 + 21n \pmod{7}\\
          & \equiv 7(2 + 3n) + 4 \pmod{7}\\
          & \equiv 4 \pmod{7}
\end{align*}
The author found the particular solution $-8$ (which corresponds to the choice $n = -2$).  However, we usually wish to express the solution of an equivalence modulo $n$ as one of the residues $0, 1, \ldots, n - 1$.  Since $n = 7$, the answer in the set of residues $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ that is equivalent modulo $7$ to $-8$ is $6$.

Comment: Quick question: Why did you break −24 into -28 + 4?

Comment: So -8 + 7n would also be a solution then?

Comment: I broke $-24$ into $-28 + 4$ since $-28 = -4 \cdot 7$, so $-28 \equiv 0 \pmod{7}$, from which we can conclude that $-24 \equiv -28 + 4 \equiv -4 \cdot 7 + 4 \equiv 4 \pmod{7}$.  In answer to your second question, $-8 + 7n$ is another way of writing the solution.  I wrote it in the form $6 + 7n$ since we usually express the solution of an equivalence modulo $m$ as a residue from the set $\{0, 1, 2, \ldots, m - 1\}$.  For $m = 7$, this means we usually choose the appropriate residue from the set $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ of remainders obtained when an integer $k = 7q + r$, with $0 \leq r < 7$.

Comment: Oh ok so both are accepted solutions then? But then isn't remainder defined as a value r that >= 0 and < m? Based off that I would think that my solution -8 + 7n isn't valid because I use a negative remainder and your solution is valid because you use a positive remainder, 6.

Comment: The best way to think of it is that $-8$ is a member of the residue class of $6 \pmod{7}$ since $-8 = 6 - 2 \cdot 7$.  By the residue class of $6 \pmod{7}$, I mean all integers $n$ that differ from $6$ by an integer multiple of $7$.  Since $-8$ and $6$ are in the same residue class, the solution $-8 + 7m, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ is valid since it produces the same set of integers as $6 + 7n, n \in \mathbb{Z}$ (take $m = n + 2$).  That said, if $n$ is an integer such that $n = qk + r$, with $0 \leq r < k$, we usually think of $n$ as belonging to the residue class of the remainder $r \pmod{k}$.