# Why is $2-(5/4) \equiv 2+5 \equiv 7 \pmod {25}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The book I am using lists something like
$x \equiv2-(5/4) \equiv 2+5 \equiv 7 \pmod {25}$

I dont understand why $(-5/4)$ seemingly turns into $5$ mod $25$

Comment: $$\dfrac{5}{4}\equiv\dfrac{5\times 6}{4\times 6}\equiv\dfrac{30}{24}\equiv \dfrac{5}{-1}\equiv -5 $$

Comment: Im curious as to where the 6 comes from here, Why can you just multiply everything by 6?

Comment: we can just multiply both sides by $6$ because $x\equiv y\pmod{n} \implies  cx \equiv cy \pmod{n}$ : $$4x\equiv 5 \pmod{25} \implies 6\times 4x \equiv 6\times 5 \pmod{25}$$

Comment: Dividing by 4 is OK mod 25 because 4 and 25 are relatively prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Because $4\cdot 19\equiv 76\equiv 1 \pmod{25}$, we have that the inverse of $4$ is $19 \pmod{25}$.  That is $\frac14 \equiv 19 \pmod{25}$.

Comment: Do you mean 76 = 1 mod 25?

Comment: Yes.  $76\equiv 1 \pmod{25}$, because they differ by a multiple of $25$.

Answer (score 3):

${\rm mod}\ 25\!:\ 4x \equiv -5\equiv 20\iff x\equiv 5,\, $ via cancel $4,\,$ valid by $\,(4,25)=1\,\Rightarrow\,4^{-1}\,$ exists.

Equivalently  $\ x\equiv \dfrac{-5}4\equiv \dfrac{20}4\equiv 5$

**Beware** $ $ Modular fraction arithmetic is well-defined only for fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion.