# Division in modular arithmetic

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Let $p$ be an odd prime. Given that $a\equiv b \pmod p$ and $c \equiv d \pmod p$, such that none of $a,b,c,d$ is a multiple of $p$. Under what conditions, $\frac{a}{c} \equiv \frac{b}{d} \pmod p$.

Comment: HINT:

$$ad-bc=d(a-b)-b(c-d)$$

Comment: You have listed all conditions already.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee thanks, done!

Comment: @Servaes thanks, can you please tell why otherwise this kind of division fails?

Comment: Congruences modulo $p$ only make sense for integers. The notation $\tfrac{1}{c}\pmod{p}$ denotes the residue class of integers that, when multiplied by $c$ are in the residue class of $1$. If $c$ is a multiple of $p$ then no such integer exists, and hence $\tfrac{1}{c}$ is not defined.

Comment: @Servaes thanks again!

Comment: @Servaes Not true, modular fractions are well defined as long as all the fractions can be represented with denominator coprime to the modulus, e.g. see [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242)