# How to prove $(11k + 5, 8 + 15k) > 1 \implies (11k + 5, 8 + 15k) = 13 \implies k \equiv 9 \pmod {13}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

How to prove $(11k + 5, 8 + 15k) > 1 \implies (11k + 5, 8 + 15k) = 13 \implies k \equiv 9 \pmod {13}$? I am able to prove the converse, but I'm having trouble with the first implication. Once I can prove that I suspect proving $(11k + 5, 8 + 15k) = 13 \implies k \equiv 9 \pmod {13}$ will not be as hard.

Comment: just add and subtract terms.  remember $\gcd(a,b) = \gcd(a + kb, b)$ etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\gcd(11k + 5, 15k + 8) = \gcd(11k + 5, 4k + 3) = \gcd(3k - 1, 4k + 3) = \gcd(3k-1, k + 4) = \gcd(-13, k+4) $

If $\gcd(-13, k+4) \ne 1$ then as $13$ is prime $\gcd(-13,k+4) = 13$ so $k+4 \equiv 0 \mod 13$ so $k \equiv 9 \mod 13$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
   \left.
   \begin{array}{c}
      g | 11k+5 \\
      g|8+15k \\
   \end{array}
   \right\}
   &\implies g|11(8+15k)-15(11k + 5) \\
   &\implies g|13 \\
   &\implies g=13 \; \text{or} \; g=1\\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
   g = 13 
   &\implies
      \left\{
      \begin{array}{l}
         13 |11k+5 \\
         13|8+15k \\
      \end{array}
      \right. \\
   &\implies 
       \left\{
       \begin{array}{rcl}
         11k +5  & \equiv 0 & \pmod{13} \\
         8 + 15k & \equiv 0 & \pmod{13} \\
      \end{array}
      \right.\\
    &\implies 2k \equiv 5 \pmod{13} \\
    &\implies k \equiv 9 \pmod{13}
\end{align}

without mods

\begin{align}
   g = 13 
   &\implies
      \left\{
      \begin{array}{l}
         13 |11k+5 \\
         13|8+15k \\
      \end{array}
      \right. \\
   &\implies 13|-4(11k+5) + 3(8+15k) \\
   &\implies 13|k+4 \\
   &\implies k+4 = 13 +13n \quad (n \in \mathbb Z)\\
   &\implies k = 9 + 13n \quad (n \in \mathbb Z)\\
   &\implies k \equiv 9 \pmod{13}
\end{align}

Comment: i.e. mod the gcd $ := d:\ \dfrac{8}{15}\equiv -k\equiv \dfrac{5}{11}\,\Rightarrow 8\cdot 11\equiv 5\cdot 15\,\Rightarrow\, 0\equiv 88-75\equiv 13.\,$ Thus $\,d\mid 13,\,$ so $\,d=13\,$ by $\,d>1.\ $

Comment: Yes, it explains what you did in the language of fractions.

Comment: @BillDubuque - took a minute, but I got it

Comment: It's another way to view the elimination of $\,k.\,$ Beware that modular fraction arithmetic is valid only for fractions with denominator coprime to the modulus [(see here).](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) Here that is true, otherwise there is a prime $\,p\mid d,15\,$ so $\,p\mid d\mid 15k+8\,$ $\Rightarrow$ $\,p\mid 8,\,$ contra $\,(15,8)=1.\,$ Similarly for $\,5/11.\ $

Answer (score 0):

$11k+5+8+15k=13+26k=13(2k+1)$ suppose that $d=(11k+5,8+13k)$ does not divide $13$, it divides $2k+1$. You have $11k+5=5(2k+1)+k$ so $d$ divides $k$, since $d$ divides $11k+5$ and $8+13k$, it divides $5$ and $8$. This implies $d=1$. Contradiction.

For the second implication check all the value in $Z/13$.

$k=0$ mod $13$, $11k+5=5$ mod 13

$k=1$ mod $13$ $8+15k=10$ mod $13$
....
$k=9$ mod 13 $11k+5=14$ mod $13$ = $13\times 8$ mod $13$ $15k+8$ = $26$ mod $13$

....

so $k=9$ is the only value which satisfies the assertion.