# Solving non linear congruence with a large mod

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Eg, solve $x^{11} \equiv 7 \pmod{61}$

The solution is $x \equiv 31 \pmod{61}$. But how do I get there? Brute checking every #, from $0 \to 60$ is very difficult?

Answer (score 7):

**Hint** $\ {\rm mod}\ 60\!:\ \color{#c00}{11^2\equiv 1},\ $ so $\,\ {\rm mod}\ 61\!:\ \left[\, x^{\large \color{#c00}{11}}\equiv 7\,\right ]^{\large \color{#c00}{11}}\!\Rightarrow\, x\equiv 7^{\large 11}\!\equiv 31$

**Remark** $\ $ If you are familar with [modular fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) then the above can be viewed more intutively as simply raising $\,x^{11}\equiv 7\pmod{61}\,$ to the power $\,\frac{1}{11}.\,$ By Fermat, the exponents are determined mod $60,\,$ and $\,\dfrac{1}{11}\equiv 11\pmod{60},\,$ which yields said solution.

Comment: Very nice. I guess in more general terms, $\color{red}{11}\cdot \color{blue}{11} \equiv 1 \bmod 60$, so $\bmod 61$, $x^\color{red}{11} \equiv 7 \implies x\equiv 7^ \color{blue}{11} $

Comment: @Joffin yes, if $\,AB\equiv 1\pmod{p-1}\,$ then $\, g(x) = x^B\,$ is the inverse of $\,f(x) = x^A\pmod p\ $

Comment: Which implies the converse holds (so no need to verify that the candidate solution is a valid solution).

Comment: Right, and the solution only exists if the exponent has an inverse in the appropriate reduced modulo (?)

Comment: @Joffan The method requires invertibility - see my Remark above.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3188192/242) for more on this method.

Answer (score 2):

All equivalences $\bmod 61$

\begin{align}
x^{11} &\equiv 7 \\
x^{22} &\equiv 49 \equiv -12 \\
x^{44} &\equiv 144 \equiv 22 \\
x^{66}  &\equiv -264 \equiv -20 \quad \equiv x^{6} \text{ by Fermat's Little Theorem}\\
x^{12} &\equiv 400 \equiv 34 \\
x &\equiv 34 \cdot 7^{-1} \equiv 34\cdot 35 \equiv 1190 \equiv 31
\end{align}

The only involved part there being finding $7^{-1} \equiv 35 \bmod 61$, which I quickly got by observing $7\cdot9 \equiv 2 $ and so  $7\cdot 36 \equiv 8 $ .

Check: $31^2 \equiv 961 \equiv 46 \equiv -15 \\
31^4 \equiv 225 \equiv 42 \equiv -19\\
31^5 \equiv -589 \equiv 21 \\
31^{10} \equiv 441 \equiv 14 \\
31^{11} \equiv 434 \equiv 7 \quad \checkmark$

Comment: How did you get $x^{11} \equiv 7 \pmod{61}$?

Comment: It was given in the question....