# Find all solutions; $17x \equiv 25 (\text{ mod } 33)$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, divisibility

> Find all solutions $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{m}$ of the following congruence
>   whereby $m$ is the modulus. If there doesn't exist a solution, state
>   why.$$17x \equiv 25 (\text{ mod } 33)$$

Alright so I have big trouble doing this because I only know how to do it if there was a $1$ instead of a $25$ on the right side : /

You then put all on one side and $33$ on the other side, use euclidean algorithm and calculate it. But what can I do in this case, when there isn't a $1$?

Is it done completely different or the same way?

Comment: It's done the same way.  You have 17x = 1 mod 33 so just go a step further 17(25x) = 25 mod 33.  So take y = 25x mod 33 and you have 17y = 25 mod 33.  The only issue is if x is the only solution to one, is 25x the only solution to twentyfive.  (and the answer to that is yes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $17$ and $33$ are coprime, i.e. $\gcd(17,33)=1$, we can find integers $m$ and $n$ for which $17m+33n=1$. We can find $m$ and $n$ by using the [Extended Eulidean Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

We see that $m=2$ and $n=-1$, which gives $17\times 2 + 33 \times(-1)=1$. Reducing both sides modulo $33$ gives $17 \times 2 \equiv 1 \bmod 33$, i.e. $2$ is the multiplicative inverse of $17$, modulo $33$.

Coming back to $17x \equiv 25 \bmod 33$. If we multiply both sides by the multiplicative inverse of $17$, i.e. $2$, we get $34x \equiv 50 \bmod 33$, i.e. $1x \equiv 17 \bmod 33$. Hence $x = 33k+17$, where $k$ is an integer.

Answer (score 2):

If you know how to solve $17y \equiv 1 \bmod 33$, then $x=25y$ is a solution of $17x \equiv 25 \bmod 33$.

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious... and if we must express x as an element of Z_33 (ie. less than 33) we simply reduce 25y mod 33.  e.g.  if y = 2 then x =25y = 25x2 = 50 = 17 mod 33.

Answer (score 2):

$$17x = 25 \pmod {33} \iff 16 x = 8 \pmod {33} \iff 2x = 1 \pmod {33}$$

Where the last comes from the fact that $8 \land 33 = 1$ (so we can "divide both sides" by $8$).

Therefore $x = 2^{-1} = 17 \pmod {33}$.

Comment: $$17x=25 (\text{ mod } 33) \Leftrightarrow 16x=8 (\text{ mod } 33)$$ How?

Comment: @berndgr $17x = 17x - 33x = -16x$, and $25 = 25 - 33 = -8$, so $-16 x = -8$ i.e. $16x = 8$.

Comment: Why did I receive $2$ downvotes? Is there something wrong with my answer?!

Comment: I didn't downvote. I gave +1 already.

Comment: You have only $1$ downvote, perhaps because you didn't motivate or justify those equiavlences?  Your method is expressed more naturally with fractions, e.g. $$ {\rm mod}\ 33\!:\ \ \frac{25}{17}\equiv \frac{-25}{-17}\equiv \frac{8}{16}\equiv \frac{1}{2}\equiv \frac{34}2\equiv 17$$  See the link in my  answer for more on modular fractions.

Comment: @BillDubuque they were $2$ when I commented - one of them got withdrawn. Thanks for the link! I never heard about modular fractions.

Answer (score 2):

Since $17$ is coprime to $33$ we can use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) to obtain $17j+33k = 1,\,$ so ${\rm mod}\ 33\!:\ 17j\equiv 1,\,$ i.e. $\,j\equiv 17^{-1}.\,$ To solve  $\,17x\equiv 25\,$ multiply both sides by $\,17^{-1}\equiv j,\,$ yielding $\, x\equiv 25j.\,$  Doing so we get $\, 17(2)-33(1) = 1\,$ so $\,17^{-1}\equiv j\equiv 2\ $ so $\ x\equiv 25(2)\equiv 17.$

---

Or we can use [Gauss's algorithm,](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) which scales the (top & bottom) of a modular fraction to make the bottom smaller when reduced mod $33$, e.g. $\,2\cdot \color{#0a0}{17}\equiv 34\equiv\color{#c00}{\bf 1} < \color{#0a0}{17}\,$ below.

$$ {\rm mod}\ 33\!:\,\ x\equiv \color{}{\dfrac{25}{\color{#0a0}{17}}}\equiv \dfrac{50}{34}\equiv \dfrac{17}{\color{#c00}{\bf 1}}$$

**Beware** $ $ Modular fraction arithmetic is valid only for fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion.

Comment: But $16$ doesn't satisfy the OP's congruence: $17 \times 16 = 272 \equiv 8 \bmod 33$.

Comment: @FlybyNight Typo fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Comment: You need to recall that ax ≡ b (mod n) has
a solution if and only if gcd(a, n) is a divisor of b. Also note that the congruence is stated modulo 33, and so the most satisfying answer is given in terms of congruence
classes modulo 33.
Solution: We have gcd(17, 33) = 1, so there is a solution since 1 is a factor of 25.
Solving the congruence 17x ≡ 25 (mod 33) is equivalent to solving the equation 17x = 25+ 33q for integers x and q. We next use trial and error to look for the multiplicative inverse of 17 modulo 33. The numbers congruent to 1 modulo 33 are 34, 67, 100, 133, etc., and −32, −65, −98, etc. Among these, we see that 17 is a factor of 34, so we multiply both sides of the congruence by 2 since (2)(17) = 34 ≡ 1 (mod 33). 
Thus we have 34x ≡50 (mod 33), or x ≡ 17 (mod 33). The solution is x ≡ 17 (mod 33).

Comment: Hi Rohan. It's great to see you answering questions. I don't know if you've heard of LaTeX of not. It's a way to type Maths and for it to look beautiful. Have a look at this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference