# Why is $34x = 50 \text{ mod } 33 \Leftrightarrow 1x = 17 \text{ mod } 33$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Why is $34x = 50 \text{ mod } 33 \Leftrightarrow 1x = 17 \text{ mod } 33$?

I have found that task on this site: [Find all solutions; $17x \equiv 25 (\text{ mod } 33)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2009439/find-all-solutions-17x-equiv-25-text-mod-33)

Looking at Bill Dubuque's answer I don't see why this is the case, how to know that so fast?

I hope someone can give an explanation so I can understand it?

Comment: Because $34\equiv 1$ and $50\equiv 17\mod 33$.

Comment: @Bernard Oh thanks Bernard, understood :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have:

$34 ≡ 1 \quad(mod 33)$

$ 50 ≡ 17\quad (mod 33)$

Using the fact that if $a ≡ b$ and $c ≡ d \quad$ (mod m), then $ac ≡ bd \quad $(mod m), we find that:

$34x ≡ x \quad  (mod 33)$

We conclude that $x ≡ 17$ (mod 33)