# $\frac{723}{104} (\bmod{61})$?

Tags: number-theory

Am I allowed to do modular arithmetic in the sense that $\frac{723}{104}\equiv \frac{723}{-18} (\bmod{61})$?

And in general how would you attack this problem?

Comment: You are supposed to compute $\frac{723}{104}$ modulo $61$, which by the very definition is a problem in modular arithmetic. So the answer to your first quation is "yes". As a first step you could replace the appearing integers by integers smaller than $61$. To systematically find $\frac{1}{104}$ modulo $61$ you could try to apply the extended Euclidean algorithm instead of just trial and error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, continuing we have $\ {\rm mod}\ 61\!:\,\ \dfrac{723}{104}\equiv \dfrac{-9}{-18}\equiv \dfrac{1}2\equiv\dfrac{62}{2}\equiv 31$

Generally we can compute modular inverses using the [Extended Euclidean Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) (which can be implemented [very conveniently by hand](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242)). But that algorithm may be  a bit overkill for small numbers, where it is often simpler to employ [Gauss's Algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242) and some twiddling as above.

**Beware** $\ $ Modular fraction arithmetic is well-defined *only* for fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion.

Comment: I'm starting to understand how efficient the Gauss Algorithm is, thanks a lot for introducing it to me.