# Prove the divisibility of $R^k_n\pm 1$ by 4

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

The question is:

> Prove that:
>
> For $n>1, R_n^k-1$ is divisible by $4$ if $k$ is even. If $k$ is odd, then $R_n^k+1$ is divisible by $4$ where $R_n$ is the rep-unit of length $n$ i.e. $R_3 = 111 , R_5 = 11111, \cdots$.

My Try:

- First we try to find $a$ such that $R_n\equiv a \pmod 4$.

Notice that we can express these *integers* as $R_n = \frac{10^n-1}{9}$. Now:
$$\frac{10^n-1}{9} \equiv a \pmod 4$$
$$10^n-1 \equiv 9a \pmod 4 \to 10^n-1 \equiv a \pmod 4$$
But $10^n$ is divisible by $4$ for any $n>1$. Hence:
$$0-1 \equiv a \pmod 4$$
Implying:

> $$a \equiv -1 \pmod 4$$

- The second step is trivial. If $k$ is odd, then $(-1)^k +1 = -1 + 1 = 0 \pmod 4$, else if $k$ is even, then $(-1)^k -1 = 1-1 = 0 \pmod 4$

Any ideas or notes on the prove?

Is there simpler way to prove so?

Comment: To prove $R_n \equiv -1 \pmod 4$, you can use the fact that $R_n = 100 * \alpha + 11 $ which can save you a few lines. The second step is really straightforward and can't be improved IMHO

Comment: @F.Carette, Thanks.

Comment: @F.Carette It's improvable by improvng the proposition to: $\ 4\mid R^k - (-1)^k.\ $ Then $\!\bmod 4\!:\,\ R\equiv -1\,\Rightarrow\, R^k\equiv (-1)^k\,$ follows immediately by the [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct. As for "simpler ways", we may  use [modular fractions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3001818/242). If $\,\gcd(b,m)=1\,$ then $\,b^{-1}$ exists $\!\bmod m\,$ and $\,a/b := ab^{-1}$ is a *unique* solution of $\,bx\equiv a\pmod{\!m},\,$ and it satisfies

$\!\bmod m\!:\,\  \begin{align}A&\equiv a\\ B&\equiv b\end{align}\ \Rightarrow\ \dfrac{A}B\equiv \dfrac{a}b \equiv  \dfrac{a\bmod m}{b\bmod m}\,\ \ {\bf if} \ \gcd(b,m)=1;\  $ thus

$\bmod \color{#c00}4\!:\,\ R_n := \dfrac{(2i)^{\large n}-1}{4j+1}\, =\, \dfrac{\color{#c00}4i^2 (2i)^{\large n-2}-1}{\color{#c00}4j+1}\,\equiv\, \dfrac{-1}1\ $ for all $\,n\ge 2$

therefore $\ R_n^{\large k}\,\equiv\, (-1)^{\large k}\ $ by [Congruence Power Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242). $ $ OP has $\,i = 5,\, j = 2$

**Beware** $\ $ Modular fraction arithmetic is well-defined *only* for fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion.