# Prove that $a \equiv b \mod n \implies\frac{a}{c} \equiv \frac{b}{c} \mod n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I’ve found this problem in a number theory book, it says:

If $a \equiv b \pmod n$ with $c>0$ and $\gcd(c,n)=1$, prove that $$\frac{a}{c} \equiv \frac{b}{c} \pmod n$$
It seems trivial but unfortunately i don’t know how to prove it .

I don’t know is it necessary to $c\mid a,b$ Because if $c\nmid a,b \implies \frac{a}{c} \notin \mathbb Z$ But modular arithmetic deals only with integers (I’m new to congruences  so maybe I’m wrong.)

Comment: In your header you are assuming $a\equiv b\pmod n$. In your post you assume $\frac bc\equiv a \pmod n$.  I assume you meant the former?  But even the former is false unless you add something like $\gcd (n,c)=1$ as an assumption.

Comment: For instance:  letting $(a,b,n)=(10,20,5)$ we certainly have $a\equiv b \pmod n$.  But now taking $c=10$ we  have  $\frac {10}{10}\not \equiv \frac {20}{10}\pmod 5$.

Comment: See the edit @lulu

Comment: Well, if $\gcd(c,n)=1$ then $c$ has a multiplicative inverse $d \pmod n$  In that case your question is just $a\equiv b\pmod n \implies ad\equiv bd\pmod n$ which is certainly true.

Comment: Hint: if gcd$(c,n)=1$ then you can find $p, q$ such that $pc+nq=1$

Comment: If you prefer to restrict to integers divisible by $c$, then write $a=cA, b=cB$,  Then $cA\equiv cB\pmod n\iff A\equiv B\pmod n$ again by multiplying by the multiplicative inverse of $c$.

Comment: Immediate consequence of the linked Congruence Product Rule - simply scale $\,a\equiv b\,$ by $\,c^{-1},\,$ which [exists by Bezout](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2326680/242) since $\,\gcd(c,n) = 1.\ $ Note $\,n/c\, :=\, n\:\! c^{-1}.\,$ See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3001866/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for more on modular fractions.