# Modular reduction of fractions [Congruence Quotient Rule]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Suppose I have this:

$\frac{6^{666}}{2^{6}}$ (mod $125$)

I saw it is possible to reduce only the numerator's power modulo Euler's phi function. Can someone explain why is that possible?

It is essentially this:

$\frac{6^{666 \space (mod \phi(125))}}{2^{6}}$ (mod $125$)

Comment: What's the question?  There's no need to reduce the exponent in $2^6$ as it is already small.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  It really isn't clear what you are asking.

Comment: My question is why it works?

Comment: Why what works?

Comment: Maybe the fact that you wrote it as a fraction is confusing you.  That's not a good way to write residue classes...The inverse of $2\pmod {125}$ is $63$, clearly, so your expression could be written as $6^{666}\times 63^6$.  Alternatively, since $6=2\times 3$, you could write your expression as $2^{660}\times 3^{666}$.

Comment: @lulu The fraction is well-defined, so "not a good way" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I know how it works when there is a normal integer with an exponent, but when there is a fraction it is applied only on the numerator's power. That is what I want to understand.

Comment: @BillDubuque  It's my sense that the fractional notation is what is confusing the OP.  Of course, I could have that wrong.

Comment: @MichaelMunta  But, where is the confusion?  You can use Euler to reduce the exponent in the denominator as well.  Of course, it's already $6$ so reducing it $\pmod {\varphi (125)} $ won't help you in any obvious way.  But the same reduction technique works for both numerator and denominator.

Comment: @MichaelMunta  If, say, you had $\frac {6^{666}}{2^{501}}$ you could use Euler to write that as $\frac {6^{66}}{2^1}\pmod {125}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is valid to mod out arguments of a fraction - just like it is for the arguments sums and products

**Lemma** $ $ If $\,(B,n)= 1\,$ then $\bmod n\!:\,\ \begin{align}A&\equiv a\\ B&\equiv b\end{align}\,\Rightarrow\, \dfrac{A}B\,\equiv\, \dfrac{a}b,\:$ i.e. $\,A \color{#c00}{B^{-1}}\equiv  a\color{#c00}{b^{-1}}$

**Proof** $\ \ $ Scaling $\: b\equiv B\:$ by $\:b^{-1}B^{-1}\Rightarrow \color{#c00}{B^{-1}\equiv b^{-1}}\,$ by CPR = [Congruence Product Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242), so multiplying that by $\, A\equiv a\, $ we obtain $\, A\color{#c00}{B^{-1}}\equiv a\color{#c00}{b^{-1}}$ again by CPR. $ $ Note $b^{-1}$ exists since $\,b\equiv B\pmod{\!n}\Rightarrow (b,n) = (B,n)=1\,$ by [gcd mod reduction](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/95825/242).

Thus the answer to your question as to "why it works" is that unwinding the definition of a fraction yields a composition of a product and inverse operation - and those operations are "compatible" with modular arithmetic (by Product and Inverse Congruence Rules) hence so too is their composition (modular "division" by *units* = invertibles = integers $B$ coprime to the modulus).

Similarly the [Polynomial Congruence Rule](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) extends to polynomial fractions (rational "functions") or to any expression composed of sum, product, and inverse operations (where the inverses all exist) by a simple inductive proof.

See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for much further discussion.

Comment: So if $B \equiv b$ then also $B^{-1} \equiv b^{-1}$?

Comment: @Michael Yes, multiply $\,B\equiv b\ $ by $\ b^{-1}B^{-1}\ $ [assuming $\,(B,n)=1,\,$ so also $\,(b,n)=(B,n)=1$] $\ \ $

Comment: It's important to realize, as Bill Dubuque pointed out, that you *must* have $\gcd(B, n) = 1$.  But if so, if $B \equiv b$ then $1\equiv B*B^{-1} \equiv b*B^{-1}$ and  $b^{-1} \equiv b^{-1}(b*B^{-1}) \equiv B^{-1}$.  Which isnt surprising as equivalence carries over multiplication and we are *multiplying* the inverses to get $1$

Answer (score 0):

As $2$ is relatively prime to $125$ then $2$ is invertable so there is a $[\frac 12]$ so that $2[\frac 12]\equiv 1 \pmod {125}$ (just let $[\frac 12] = 63$ but we don't actually care what $[\frac 12]$ is; just that it exists) so for any $m = 2^jb$ then $\frac m{2^j}\equiv \frac m{2^j}(2^j*[\frac 12]^j) \equiv m*[\frac 12]^j$.

So $\frac {6^{666}}{2^6} \equiv 6^{666}[\frac 12]^6 \equiv 6^{\phi (666)}[\frac 12]^6\pmod {125}$

For notation purposes it is pefectly acceptable to write $\frac 12 \equiv 63 \pmod {125}$ and to use the fraction notation.  (Although it's perhaps misleading to use the $2^{-1} \equiv 63 \pmod {125}$ notation instead.)

It's just important to realize that the residuce class is *not* $\{\frac 12 + 125k| k \in \mathbb Z\}$ but $\{m|2m \equiv 1 \pmod 125\} = \{m|\exists k\in \mathbb Z; 2m = 1 + 125k\}=\{m|2m = 1 + 125k$ for some odd $k\} =\{\frac {1+125(2k+1)}2| k \in \mathbb Z\}=\{63+ 125k|k \in \mathbb Z\}$.

And it's important to realize that if $k$ and $n$ arent relatively prime there *isn't* and such $k^{-1} \mod n$ and we can't use $\frac 1k \pmod n$