# Congruence. How would you prove this set equality? (congruence division)

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I'd like to prove $$3+4\mathbb Z = \{ x\in \mathbb Z , 3x \equiv 5 [4]\}$$

The $\Rightarrow$ is trivial: $x\in 3+4\mathbb Z \Rightarrow x\equiv3[4] \Rightarrow 3x\equiv5[4]$

But for the reverse way $\Leftarrow$ I get stuck at a certain point: $3x\equiv 5[4] \Rightarrow 3x\equiv 1[4]$

I am stuck at this point..

PS: I've been thinking about [dividing $3x\equiv 1[4]$  by $3\equiv 3 [4]$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3091180/1021982) which I can do because $gcd(3,4)=1$

but then I would  have $\frac{1}{3}$ which is difficult to handle.

Comment: $\bmod 4\!:\ 3x\equiv 5\iff -x\equiv 1\iff x\equiv -1\equiv 3\iff x \in 3+4\Bbb Z\,$ by [basic congruence arithmetic laws](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reverse, suppose we have

$\tag 1 3x = 4n + 5$

We need to find $m$ such that

$\quad x = 4m + 3$

This is possible if we can show that $x -3$ is divisible by $4$, which would also be true if $3 \cdot (x-3)$ is divisible by $4$. But, using $\text{(1)}$,

$\tag 3 3 (x-3) = 4n + 5-9 = 4n -4 = 4(n-1)$

and so all is good.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 1):

$3x \equiv 1 [4] \Rightarrow 3x \equiv 1+8 [4]$ which gives $3x \equiv 9 [4]$ and $x \equiv 3 [4]$ since $(3,4)=1$.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).