# Find the remainder when $2^{837259739}+ 3^{23456}$ is divided by $31$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

for $2$ I was able to solve it by going from

$$(2^5)^{167451947} \cdot 2^4$$ which is congruent to $1(\mod 31)$ and $16(\mod31)$ respectively.

I just don't know if I'm doing the $3$ part correctly.  Would $(3^3)^{7818} \cdot 3^2$ be $27(\mod31)$ and $9(\mod31)$ respectively?

Comment: You can use $a^{n-1}=1 (mod n)$, because gcd(3,31)=1.

Comment: Or, you can break 23456 by prime factorization. $23456={3^2}*67*389$. Then, use my last comment.

Comment: For doing the $3^29$ part or the $3^26$ part, remember $3^3=-4 (mod 31)$ and what you wrote in the question: $2^5=1 (mod\;31)$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((3%5E3)%5E7818)%E2%8B%853%5E2+(mod31)) says $${3^3}^{7818}*3^2$$ (mod31) is 18. I guess the two add together to make 27.

Answer (score 2):

Below are a few easy ways to calculate $\,3^{\large 23456}\!\equiv 3^{\large 23456\bmod\color{#0a0}{30}}\!\pmod{\!31}\ $ by little $\rm\color{#0a0}{Fermat}$.

First note $\!\bmod\color{#0a0}{30}\!:\ 23456 \equiv 23430+26\equiv\color{#c00}{26}\,$ by $\,3,10\mid 23430\,$ by $\,3\mid 2\!+\!3\!+\!4\!+\!3$

So $\ \ 3^{\large 3}\equiv -2^{\large 2}\overset{(\ \ )^{\LARGE 8}}\Longrightarrow\,3^{\large 24}\equiv 2(2^{\large 5})^{\large 3}\equiv 2$ $\,\overset{\large \times 3^{\Large 2}}\Longrightarrow 3^{\large\color{#c00}{26}} \equiv 18,\, $ using only easy mental arithmetic.

**Or** $\,\ 3^{\large\color{#0a0}{30}}\!\equiv 1\,\Rightarrow\,3^{\large\color{#c00}{26}}\!\equiv \dfrac{1}{3\cdot 3^{\large 3}}\equiv \dfrac{1}{3(-4)}\equiv\dfrac{3}{-36}\equiv  \dfrac{3}{-5}\equiv \dfrac{18}{-30}\equiv 18\ $ by [Gauss's algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242)

**Alternatively** by factoring above $\,  \dfrac{-1}3\,\dfrac{1}4\equiv \dfrac{30}3\,\dfrac{32}4\equiv 10(8)\equiv 18,\, $  easy mentally all $3$ ways!

**Beware** $\ $ Modular fraction arithmetic is well-defined only for fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion.

Comment: so do I add the 18 with 1mod(31) and 16mod(31) to get my final answer?

Comment: @KayyWang $\bmod 31:\  a\equiv 16,\ b\equiv 18\,\Rightarrow\, a+b\equiv 16+18\equiv 3\ \ $