# Find $4x \equiv 7 \pmod{15}$ and $3x \equiv 5 \pmod{16}$ (different exercises)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

This is how I solved each:

$$4x \equiv 7\pmod {15} \\
4x - 7 \equiv 0\pmod{15} \\
4x-7 = 15k \Leftrightarrow 4x-15k= 7 \\
$$

$$15 = 4*3+3 \\
4=3*1+1\\
3=3*1+0$$

$$1 = 4-3*1 \\
3 = 15-4*3 \\
1 = 4 - (15-4*3)*1 \\
1 = 4-15+4*3 \\
1 = 4*4-15*1 \\
$$

$$7 = (7*4)*4-(7*1)*15$$

$7*4*4 = 112$ which is congruent with 7 in mod 15. Yet my book says the answer is 13. What went wrong?

The second one:

$$3x - 5 \equiv 0 \pmod{16} \\
3x-5=16k\\
3x-16k=5 \\$$

$$16=3*5+1\\
3=1*3+0$$

$$1 = 16-3*5 \\
5=16*5-3*5*5$$

Yet $3*5*5-5$ is not congruent with zero in mod 16. What went wrong?

Comment: For the first one,  you need only to take $$7*4 = 28 \equiv 13 \pmod{15}.$$ The second one,  $3*5*5 + 5$ is zero in modulo $16$.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that with such computations! For each of these congruence equations, you just have to find the modular inverse of the coefficient (which happens to be a modular unit since it is coprime to the modulus).

*Example* for the first congruence:

The modular inverse of $4\bmod 15$ is none other than itself since $4^2=16\equiv 1\mod 15$. So multiply both sides of the congruence equation by $4$:
$$4x\equiv 7\mod 15\implies 4^2x\equiv \color{red}x\equiv 4\cdot 7=28\color{red}{\equiv 13\mod 15}.$$

Comment: Can't I find the modular inverse using the Euclidean algorithm?

Comment: But the OP's method of scaling the Bezout identity is equivalent to what you propose (and even a method you have used in the past iirc).

Answer (score 1):

To *correctly*  pattern-match $\,\color{#c00}x\,$ in the above $\,\rm\color{#0a0}{scaled}\,$ Bezout equations do as follows.

$\qquad\ \begin{align}
\ -7\cdot \color{#90f}{15}&\ +\ 4\cdot 7\cdot 4\,\  =\ \color{#0a0} 7\ \ [=\ \color{#0a0}{7\ {\rm times}} {\rm \ Bezout\ of\ } \gcd(15,4)=1\,]\\[.2em]
\Rightarrow\ \bmod \color{#90f}{15}&\!:\,\ \  \ \  4\cdot\color{#c00}{ 7\cdot 4} \ \equiv\ \ 7\\
\rm so &\,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ 4\ \cdot\  \color{#c00} x\ \ \, \equiv\, \ \ 7\ \ \ {\rm for}\ \ \ \color{#c00}{x\equiv 7\cdot 4}\equiv 13  \\[.6em]
\ 5\cdot \color{#90f}{16}&\, + 3\cdot 5(-5)\, =\, \color{#0a0}5\ \ [=\ \color{#0a0}{5\ {\rm times}} {\rm \ Bezout\ of\ } \gcd(16,3)=1\,]\\[.2em]
\Rightarrow\ \bmod \color{#90f}{16}&\!:\,\ \  3\cdot\color{#c00}{ 5(-5)}\, \equiv\ 5\\
\rm so &\,\ \ \ \ \   3\ \cdot\  \color{#c00} x\ \ \ \,\equiv\ \ \ \ 5\ \ \  {\rm for}\ \ \ \color{#c00}{x\equiv 5(-5)}\equiv 7
\end{align}$

**Simpler** $\bmod 15\!:\,\ 4x\equiv7\iff x \equiv \dfrac{7}{4}\equiv \dfrac{-8}4\equiv -2\equiv 13$

Similarly $\bmod 16\!:\,\ 3x\equiv 5\iff x\equiv \dfrac{5}3\equiv\dfrac{21}3\equiv 7\ $ where we subtracted or added the modulus to the numerator to make the division *exact*, a special case of [Inverse Reciprocity](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/174687/242).

**Beware** $\ $ Modular fraction arithmetic is well-defined only for fractions with denominator *coprime* to the modulus. [See here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/921093/242) for further discussion.

Answer (score 1):

With such small coefficients ($4$ and $3$), here is a quick and easy way to solve the congruences:

Mod $15$:  $4x\equiv7\equiv22\equiv37\equiv\color{red}{52}=4\times13\implies x\equiv 13$

Mod $16$:  $3x\equiv5\equiv\color{red}{21}=3\times7\implies x\equiv 7$

Comment: That's essentially the same as I did but without using fractions. As I mentioned there it can be done *algorithmically* by Inverse Reciprocity, which computes the exact multiple needed to make the quotient *exact*.

Answer (score 0):

You arrived at $7=28(4)-7(15)$, which means $7\equiv 4(28)-7(15)\equiv4(28)\equiv4(\boxed{13})$ (mod 15).

Similarly, $5=16(5)-3(25)$, means $5\equiv-3(25)\equiv-3(-7)\equiv3(\boxed{7})$ (mod 16).

You made a mistake in the second part because you forgot to take into account the negative sign.